# ASP.NET Forms Authentication always false despite successful login

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to learn how to do user authentication with ASP.NET. I've set up the following simple site to experiment with it, but I'm running into a login loop because my authentication seems to always return 'false'.

Here's my code:

The login page has an  control named Login1.

Here's the code behind;

```
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userId = -1;

    string connectionString = ""; // I have a connection string here that I left out of this post.
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    using (conn)
    {            
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Validate_User"))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", Login1.UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pass", Login1.Password);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ireturnvalue", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                cmd.Parameters["@ireturnvalue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ireturnvalue"].Value.ToString());
                switch (userId)
                {
                    case -1:
                        Login1.FailureText = "DB call failed, contact System Admin.";
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, false);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        firstLogin = true;
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, false);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);                            
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested that the login is successful and with my test user we end up at 'case 2' in the switch statement. From my understanding, this should set up the cookie and then redirect the user back to the page they were trying to go to.

In this case, that would be my Members.aspx page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
}
```

So this should detect if the user is authenticated and if they're not, redirect them to the login page. Here's where the issue arises, as this always returns false and so always redirects back to the login page.

Here are some additional settings I know are important based on the related questions:

In Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="2880"/>    
</authentication>
```

Also:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

Some people have suggested also adding the following to Web.config, but I run into a 'localhost redirected you too many times' error when I add it:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I've tried a number of suggestions on related questions, many of which have me tinker with some Web.Config setting (such as the  setting) or a few that are using the Membership.ValidateUser function, which isn't what the tutorial I followed had me do.

For reference, here's the tutorial I followed: [ASP.NET Authentication Tutorial.](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Form-based-authentication-example-in-ASPNet.aspx)

I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with authenticating, but I'm not sure what else should be done besides using the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, false) method.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding the location in your web.config? <location path="YourPage.aspx"> and allowing the user or group. Also Add this for at least your login page and registeration page.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean adding:
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

If so, I did just try this and am seeing the same behavior, but this might fix the <deny users="?"> issue I was having.

Comment: Yes. <deny users = "?" > will stop anonymous access to all the pages in your application which is fine. Also, add the "Members.aspx" as a location in your config with <allow users = "testUser" > and see if it makes a difference.I doubt it will though, but worth a try.

Comment: Doing so doesn't seem to make a difference. This makes sense though, since the page load for the members.aspx page has the FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(). So even if the page allowed anonymous browsing, that would show authentication as being false and redirect.

Comment: Here's one question though.Why are you checking User.Identity.IsAuthenticated on every page? If the user is authenticated and the Cookie has been created, the framework will allow you to access the page. If you directly try to access the Members page it will redirect you to the login page for credentials. It the duty of the .net framework to manage it.

Comment: Can you try commenting out the Config to remove the modules in web.config.

Comment: @VarunMehta As I said, I was following a tutorial and that was the method they had guided me through. I'm gathering there is a more modern/better way of handling authentication.

The answer below did solve the issue, so I didn't try commenting out the section you suggested.

I appreciate you troubleshooting with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Namely, we need to instruct IIS 7.0 to use ASP.NET's FormsAuthenticationModule and UrlAuthorizationModule while processing requests. Add the  element to the web application's root Web.config file, remove the existing definitions for the FormsAuthenticationModule and UrlAuthorization modules and add them back in using ASP.NET's versions

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135904/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122408-1.aspx

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
     <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
     <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />

     <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
     <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
  </modules>
```

This is an old article and may or may not apply. I don't have this in my web.config (remove or add) and forms auth works fine. (it might depend on the 'provider'?)

Comment: This does fix the issue. Thanks for providing the link. I'm going to spend some time understanding this.